# How to exclude Test files From Searches in VS Code?

Tags: vs-code, regular-expressions

Is it possible to exclude test files when doing a grep search in VS Code?

I would have thought one of these regexes would have worked
`^/(?!Test$)[a-z0-9]+$` Or
`^/(?!Test)([a-z0-9]+)$`

Answer (score 3):

Search in VS Code doesn't utilize regex in excluding files (see [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1214)). It is configured with [glob patterns](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options). So you can still do the following:

- files to exclude: `*Test.cls`

This, of course, assumes your test classes are named with `test` at the end (ex. `MyControllerTest.cls`). If it's in the front just flip that around

- files to exclude: `Test*.cls`

Likewise, you can include multiple paths to exclude to cover different permutations by separating them with a comma:

- files to exclude: `*test.cls, *Test.cls, Test*.cls`

[image]

If you don't want to specify each time, you can edit your workspace/user settings (File --> Preferences --> Settings)

[image]

As the documentation notes, excluding a file pattern in the settings has a slight difference than directly in the search.

> Note that glob patterns in the search view work differently than in settings such as files.exclude and search.exclude. In the settings, you must use **/example to match a folder named example in subfolder folder1/example in your workspace. In the search view, the ** prefix is assumed. The glob patterns in these settings are always evaluated relative to the path of the workspace folder.